# Trying to add a timer to my website to countdown days

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I'm trying to get a timer to count down to a date by days and I don't know why this isn't working it just says NaN

```js
function daysUntil24thApril2016() {
  var april2016 = new Date(24, 4, 2016);
  var difference = april2016.getMilliseconds - Date.now().getMilliseconds;
  return difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("asdasd")
  $('#dateTime').text(daysUntil24thApril2016());
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: I explained what went wrong with his code in my answer, so hopefully he understands how to make calculation work "his way". There might be an easier/faster way, but understanding what was wrong is the first way in getting it right.

Answer (score 3):

There are several mistakes you made in your script, I'll try to explain each to help you understand it and finally give you a corrected script the way you wrote it:

1. `new Date()` wants the `year` first, then `month - 1` and finally the days. So to get the 24.04.2016, you have to do `new Date(2016, 3, 24)`
2. For a `Date` there is a `getMilliseconds` function, but it returns the milliseconds part of that date, not the unix timestamp you wanted
3. `.getTime()` is the function to get the unix timestamp in milliseconds from this date
4. `Date.now()` already returns the unix timestamp (a number), there is no `getMilliseconds()` for that and therefore it returned `undefined`
5. Even if there were a `getMilliseconds` function, the way you wrote it without the braces `()` would not have called it anyway but returned the function. They way you wrote it resulted in `var difference = function - undefined` which is `NaN`: "Not a number".
6. Therefore `difference` was no number in your example (it was `Nan`) and you cannot do any math with it obviously, it stays `NaN`
7. Using `Math.floor` will give you full days

See below for a version of your script where the points above are corrected.

```js
function daysUntil24thApril2016() {
  var april2016 = new Date(2016, 3, 24);
  var difference = april2016.getTime() - Date.now();
  return Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dateTime').text(daysUntil24thApril2016());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dateTime"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will solve your problem:

```
function daysUntil24thApril2016() {
  var april2016 = new Date("2015-04-24");
  var difference = Date.now()-april2016;
  return Math.floor((difference) / (1000*60*60*24)) 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(daysUntil24thApril2016());
});
```

When you subtract one `Date` object from another you will get the time difference in milliseconds. Using `Math.floor()` will return a whole (integer) number of days.